# "Not enough storage is available to complete this operation"- JQuery error when loading JSON files

Tags: jquery, json, memory, out-of-memory, c3.js

I'm working using `C3 charts` that loads 3 JSON files to display data.

> I use AJAX to load 3 JSON files when the page loads and we have to use IE11.
>
> When ever the page loads, I keep on receiving this error "Not enough storage is available to complete this operation" in the jQuery file.

I apply a code that will disable cache, though, it works for a short time then the error appears. Please, can you insist me? My team and I been searching for a solution for this error.

Is there a work around or a solution for this issue? Or is there a library that can manage it's memory during the page load?

FYI,

> The total MB of those 3 JSON files are 140mb. Below is the code i use for getting the JSON files. I need these files to make the c3 chart work and fetching the information when clicking the bars. The last 2 AJAX are just storing the result into the JavaScript object.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "data/parsedAfterBlueBarClicked.json",
  type: "GET",
  dataType: "json",
  complete: function() { 
    //Remove the loading percentage div....
  },
  progress: function(evt) {
    if (evt.lengthComputable) {
      $(".loadingText").html("Loading... " +  parseInt( (evt.loaded / evt.total * 100), 10) + "%");            
    } else {
      console.log("Length not computable.");
    }
  },
  progressUpload: function(evt) {
    // See above
  },
  success: function(data) {
    getGroupAndItemsJSON = data;
  } 
});

//get groupDetails JSON using AJAX 
$.getJSON("data/parsedGroupDetails.json", function(result) {
  getGroupDetailsJSON = result;
}).fail(function() {
  console.log("failed to load parsedGroupDetails.json");
}).done(function() {
  parsedGroupDetailsDone = true;
});  
        
//begin .getJSON for file parsedOrangeBarGraph.json
//  data/groupFilterItems.json
$.getJSON("data/parsedOrangeBarGraph.json", function(result) {
  getlistGroupAndItemsArray = result;
}).fail(function() {
  console.log("failed to load parsedOrangeBarGraph.json");
}).done(function() {
  parsedOrangeBarGraphDone = true;
});
```

Thank you!

Comment: You're loading 140Mb of data. That's your problem. You need to find a way of loading less data in a single request. Paging, filtering etc.

Comment: 140 mb is really to much data, are you  getting only usefull data? if any of your axis suppose x, have some range, you can make a range filter, and then show the data that is selected in range,

Comment: try it in private brawser once , don't reload the page again and again. 
and close the IE completely first, and run IE 64bit  mode

Comment: Thanks for your response.Yes,  the data from the 3 JSON files are coming from one excel spreadsheet that have over 100k rows. We use JAVA to parse the excel spreadsheet into a JSON files to a format that we can grab a specific data when interacting the c3 chart. ex: the y axis are the number of items and x axis are the 72 hours. clicking the bars to view the list of detail items in that hour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solve my problem. Yes, the best approach is to load those JSON files in the back end (JAVA side). So when i click the bars from the C3 chart, all i need is to grab the index number. Take that index and use Ajax to call another JSP file to send the index value into a java method. The index value will fetch the data from an JSON object in JAVA (JSON file is already loaded in the JAVA side and store it into a JAVA Bean getters/setters). Then take the data back and send an response. Works well and i click refreshed over 15 times and i have not seen that error. I hope this explains well.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you need to think of a different approach for this one. Loading 140mb of data at once is out of the question. Maybe in 2117 that will be normal, but that's not the case today!

I'm thinking this is gotta be a huge table case you need to display. Therefore, in that scenario, you should break it down in several segments, loading only when requested for. For exemple, you can send like 20~50 rows at once and then perform another select if the user chooses for, bringing new json for the next page.

I may be extrapolating the assumptions here, and I'm sorry for that, but if, still in the huge table scenario, you're worried about filters, don't be. You can always perform new requests to your database using the filters in hand. That will speed up the search.

Comment: Thank you for you response! Yea that feature is there for displaying 50 data and when scrolling down it loads 50 more. (I'm using a slicing functions for the JSON detail files). I was thinking instead of loading 140 mb, when clicking the bar to view the details, i can grab the index from the bar chart. Take that index and use it for ajax to call a java file. In the java file, take that index and use the json file to grab the json objects (data) and send a response of that JSON objects to display the details. Is that a good approach?

Comment: So, you're basically telling me that 50 rows of what you have has got 140MB??? There's gotta be something wrong... I didn't have your other comments before I posted that first answer. Now that I know it's a spreadsheet, I would advise you to simply import that into a database table and do a regular old fashioned select top 50 each time. Couldn't it be done? It would dramatically help you with this overhead.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. No, the 3 JSON files are the total of 140MB. Each files have format differently so I can fetch the data depends on what is click on the c3 chart and a table. Fetching and displaying the data is fine but sometimes the browser crash when its loading those 3 json files while the page loads. I'm doing this because I will have these files ready when interacting the c3 chart. I was thinking instead of loading the json files in front end, have it loaded in java side. Not sure if this is bad approach. I'm new at this.. Thanks guys for responding!

Comment: I see it now! And, no, that's actually the good approach. The heavy stuff is what server side is for. Use the front end to fetch things in your java back end when needed, but fetching small data is a must. You can use ajax requests for that.

Comment: Awesome! I will go forward with this approach. I'll post my status  if things went well or not. Thank you!